# Android TV box closes my application in 10 seconds

Tags: android, arm, gpu, android-tv, egl

I am developing an **android application** which is basically a **crossfade media player**. The only difference of it from the other mediaplayers is that it has a crossfade functionality which is when the current song is ending it is starting to fade out and the next song is starting fade in.

My problem is when I install my app to the Android TV box (Rockchip MX10 Api 9 RAM: 4GB ROM: 32GB) the device closes my app after nearly 10 seconds.

However my application works on a different Android TV box(Rockchip MX9 Api 7 RAM: 2GB ROM: 16GB)

Additionally the application works on my Samsung Galaxy J8 phone (Api 9)

At first there is a login screen, and the box does not close the app in that screen. But once you log in, and the first song starts, after a few seconds, the box closes my app. So I suspect that is a performance issue.

Following is the logcat. (Not full of it but the rest of it does not contain any error and the time is not changing much, the last line is also written at the same seconds just have a difference as milliseconds)

```
2019-10-17 11:43:13.910 5323-5323/? I/Zygote: seccomp disabled by setenforce 0
2019-10-17 11:43:13.918 5323-5323/? I/omus.androidap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-10-17 11:43:14.104 5323-5330/? E/omus.androidap: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2019-10-17 11:43:14.183 5323-5323/? I/omus.androidap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-17 11:43:15.379 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp D/ROCKCHIP: android/app/ResourcesManager.java packageName = com.company.androidapp
2019-10-17 11:43:15.407 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-10-17 11:43:15.407 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-10-17 11:43:15.407 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-10-17 11:43:15.407 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-10-17 11:43:15.407 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-10-17 11:43:15.433 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization
2019-10-17 11:43:15.605 5323-5323/com.company.androidapp I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
2019-10-17 11:43:15.836 5323-5347/com.company.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Long monitor contention with owner Queue (5341) at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoStrategy io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.getReflectionStrategy()(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:103) waiters=0 in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfo io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.getAdvertisingInfo() for 237ms
2019-10-17 11:43:15.839 5323-5350/com.company.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Long monitor contention with owner Queue (5341) at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoStrategy io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.getReflectionStrategy()(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:103) waiters=1 in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfo io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.getAdvertisingInfo() for 176ms
2019-10-17 11:43:15.903 5323-5341/com.company.androidapp D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2019-10-17 11:43:15.912 5323-5354/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/stetho: Listening on @stetho_br.com.gomus.androidapp_devtools_remote
2019-10-17 11:43:15.937 5323-5341/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
2019-10-17 11:43:15.445 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/ROCKCHIP: android/app/ResourcesManager.java packageName = br.com.gomus.androidapp
2019-10-17 11:44:46.165 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5fa473f
2019-10-17 11:44:46.190 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/ROCKCHIP: android/app/ResourcesManager.java packageName = br.com.gomus.androidapp
2019-10-17 11:44:46.215 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/ROCKCHIP: android/app/ResourcesManager.java packageName = br.com.gomus.androidapp
2019-10-17 11:44:46.505 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.508 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.535 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PERMISSION: REQUEST LOG PERMISSION
2019-10-17 11:44:46.570 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-17 11:44:46.631 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/rockchip/mali_so_src_of_utgard/./src/base/arch/arch_011_udd/base_arch_main.c; [Line] : 561; [Func] : deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
    arm_release_ver of this mali_so is 'r7p0-00rel1', rk_so_ver is '3@0', built at '14:07:59', on 'Dec  4 2018'.
2019-10-17 11:44:46.632 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/rockchip/mali_so_src_of_utgard/./src/base/arch/arch_011_udd/base_arch_main.c; [Line] : 574; [Func] : deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
    mali_ver_property has been set to 'r7p0-00rel1-5-3@0', to return.
2019-10-17 11:44:46.641 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-17 11:44:46.642 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-17 11:44:46.642 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: FindAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: FindAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: ModifyAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: ModifyAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.701 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:347): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=2385 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2019-10-17 11:44:46.703 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/GRALLOC-ROCKCHIP: RK_GRAPHICS_VER=commit-id:b0c117e
2019-10-17 11:44:48.856 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/splash act: getToken = aGF2YWlhbmFzLmhpbGFsOmhpbGFs
2019-10-17 11:44:48.857 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/splash act: new Random().nextInt() = -2068552007
2019-10-17 11:44:48.874 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/INTENT NAV Splash: Initial Download | value = true
2019-10-17 11:44:48.893 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@fa84f34
2019-10-17 11:44:48.970 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/before: Logcat save
2019-10-17 11:44:48.974 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/getFilesDir(): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.gomus.androidapp/files/TestFolder/Logging.txt
2019-10-17 11:44:49.247 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/LocalDatabaseImpl: br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.model.PlaylistSchedulefindRealmObject realmQuery.findAll = []
2019-10-17 11:44:49.290 5323-5421/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistMapper: copyFromRealmResults playlist.getName = Havaianas.entrada
2019-10-17 11:44:49.290 5323-5421/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistMapper: deepCopy = playlist == NOT null
2019-10-17 11:44:49.571 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.571 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.571 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.572 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.572 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.573 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.757 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:49.762 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: onResume
2019-10-17 11:44:49.763 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlaYerRepo: userToken = aGF2YWlhbmFzLmhpbGFsOmhpbGFs
2019-10-17 11:44:49.774 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/LocalDatabaseImpl: br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.model.PlaylistSchedulefindRealmObject realmQuery.findAll = []
2019-10-17 11:44:49.775 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlayerInteractor: elegiblePlaylists.size() <= 0
2019-10-17 11:44:49.776 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistDaoImpl: findFirstAsync = 
2019-10-17 11:44:49.796 5323-5423/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/LocalDatabaseImpl: findFirstAsync= Playlist = proxy[{id:20544},{name:Havaianas.entrada},{updateAt:1569951784},{songs:SongsIdResponse},{videos:null},{isVideo:false},{userToken:aGF2YWlhbmFzLmhpbGFsOmhpbGFs},{needShuffle:false}]
2019-10-17 11:44:49.797 5323-5423/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistMapper: deepCopy = playlist == NOT null
2019-10-17 11:44:49.799 5323-5423/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlayerInteractor: first playlist name = Havaianas.entrada
2019-10-17 11:44:49.811 5323-5423/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlayerVM: checkWhatIsFirstScreenByCurrentPlaylist
2019-10-17 11:44:49.834 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: onResume
2019-10-17 11:44:50.072 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:50.072 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:50.073 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp W/omus.androidap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 11:44:50.115 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PreferencesManagerImpl: saveSongs mPendentDownloadItems2PENDENT_DOWNLOAD_ITEMS
2019-10-17 11:44:50.116 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/DownloadRepositoryImpl: calculateSavedProgress mTotalItems0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.116 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PreferencesManagerImpl: saveSongs mPendentDownloadItems2DOWNLOADED_ITEMS
2019-10-17 11:44:50.117 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/DownloadRepositoryImpl: calculateSavedProgress mItemsDownloaded0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.118 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/DownloadRepositoryImpl: mItemsDownloaded: 0 mTotalItems0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.118 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/DownloadRepositoryImpl: Current progress : 100 %
2019-10-17 11:44:50.154 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: changeToMusicFragment
2019-10-17 11:44:50.190 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: replaceFragment
2019-10-17 11:44:50.197 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlayerInteractor: requestCurrentPlaybackInfo  is called
2019-10-17 11:44:50.198 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MediaPlayerVM: mUpdateFinishedNOT
2019-10-17 11:44:50.407 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistScheduleService: Avoiding call interactor in a thread without a loop!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.409 5323-5426/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/1stReportService: Trying to send report
2019-10-17 11:44:50.413 5323-5426/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/REPORT: FIRST REPORT | No gps permission!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.415 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/PlaylistScheduleService: Serviço foi reinicializado com 1 minuto DE DELAY!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.421 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/LocalDatabaseImpl: br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.model.ScheduleCompoundfindRealmObject realmQuery.findAll = []
2019-10-17 11:44:50.422 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/2ndReportService: Trying to send report
2019-10-17 11:44:50.423 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/SpotSchedulerRepositoryImpl: getSpotsScheduledList[]
2019-10-17 11:44:50.431 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerFragment: onCreateViewbr.com.gomus.androidappui.main.MediaPlayerActivity
2019-10-17 11:44:50.438 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/SERVICE - SPOT: ACTUAL Current time and date: 2019-10-17 14:44:50 - HOURS: 14:44 - DAYS: 17 - MONTH: 10 - MONTH LENGTH: 2mSpotScheduleList0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.439 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/SpotSchedulerService: Serviço foi reinicializado com 60 SEGUNDOS DE DELAY!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.440 5323-5426/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/REPORT: GomusApplication.getInstance().isPlaying()= false
2019-10-17 11:44:50.441 5323-5426/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/FIRST-REPORT: FIRST REPORT | Id = 1735875982 | Date = 2019-10-17 14:44:50 | AudioPercentage = 20 | Playing = false | Longitude = 0.0 | Latitude = 0.0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.447 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/REPORT: SECOND REPORT | Realm results are not empty!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.448 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateService: onHandleWorkstartService
2019-10-17 11:44:50.449 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateService: !hasPendentUpdate()
2019-10-17 11:44:50.449 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateService: checkUpdates()
2019-10-17 11:44:50.450 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateService: sendCheckingUpdateBroadcast
2019-10-17 11:44:50.452 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateContentInteractorImpl: checkHasUpdates
2019-10-17 11:44:50.452 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/UpdateContentRemoteRepositoryImpl: checkHasUpdates= 
2019-10-17 11:44:50.459 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/CheckConnectionTask: success HyperLog
2019-10-17 11:44:50.461 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/CheckConnectionTask: doInBackground
2019-10-17 11:44:50.469 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/REPORT: SECOND REPORT | Realm results are empty!
2019-10-17 11:44:50.472 5323-5425/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/SECOND-REPORT: SECOND REPORT | Id = 1735875982 | AppVersion = 1.41.19 | SO Version = 9 | RAM Size = 3,919MB | Space in Disk = 10,849MB | Date = 2019-10-17 14:44:50 | Songs Downloaded = 1 | Execution Details = 0
2019-10-17 11:44:50.486 5323-5424/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/CheckConnectionTask: doInBackground try
2019-10-17 11:44:50.664 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> POST http://echo.gomus.com.br/player/player3_report_executions.json
2019-10-17 11:44:50.664 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> POST http://echo.gomus.com.br/player/player3_report_ping.json
2019-10-17 11:44:50.664 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-10-17 11:44:50.664 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-10-17 11:44:50.665 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 116
2019-10-17 11:44:50.665 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 174
2019-10-17 11:44:50.665 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Authorization: aGF2YWlhbmFzLmhpbGFsOmhpbGFs
2019-10-17 11:44:50.665 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: Authorization: aGF2YWlhbmFzLmhpbGFsOmhpbGFs
2019-10-17 11:44:50.666 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: {"audioPercentage":20,"date":"2019-10-17 14:44:50","id":1735875982,"isPlaying":false,"latitude":0.0,"longitude":0.0}
2019-10-17 11:44:50.666 5323-5429/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (116-byte body)
2019-10-17 11:44:50.666 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: {"appVersion":"1.41.19","date":"2019-10-17 14:44:50","executionDetails":[],"id":1735875982,"ramMemory":"3,919MB","soVersion":"9","songsDownloaded":1,"spaceInDisk":"10,849MB"}
2019-10-17 11:44:50.667 5323-5430/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (174-byte body)
2019-10-17 11:44:50.711 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerFragment: onCreateView2
2019-10-17 11:44:50.712 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerViewModel: loadCurrentPlaylist
2019-10-17 11:44:50.713 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerViewModel: !mInteractor.isStarted()
2019-10-17 11:44:50.713 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerViewModel: loadPlaylist()
2019-10-17 11:44:50.714 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: startCurrentPlaylist Havaianas.entrada
2019-10-17 11:44:50.714 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: inside checkIfCallbackAttached() 
2019-10-17 11:44:50.715 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: 00mMediaPlayerInterface == null || !mMediaPlayerInterface.isPlaybackCallbackDetached()
2019-10-17 11:44:50.715 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerInteractor: startCurrentPlaylist mCurrentPlaylists Havaianas.entrada
2019-10-17 11:44:50.750 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp D/MusicPlayerFragment: onResume
2019-10-17 11:44:50.760 5323-5323/br.com.gomus.androidapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I suspect from these lines:

```
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: FindAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: FindAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: ModifyAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
2019-10-17 11:44:46.643 5323-5405/br.com.gomus.androidapp E/MaliEGL: ModifyAppHintInFile open fail errno=0x2  (No such file or directory)
```

And unfortunately there are no enough information about these in internet.

**UPDATE**

To improve the topic I wanted to add the results of the `./adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo` command. As you can see **Janky frames: 2 (100.00%)**. I do not understand, this janky frame is lower in my samsung galaxy j8 device.

```
Applications Graphics Acceleration Info:
Uptime: 24088494 Realtime: 24088494

** Graphics info for pid 20341 [br.com.gomus.androidapp] **

Stats since: 24075749808985ns
Total frames rendered: 2
Janky frames: 2 (100.00%)
50th percentile: 1000ms
90th percentile: 1000ms
95th percentile: 1000ms
99th percentile: 1000ms
Number Missed Vsync: 2
Number High input latency: 0
Number Slow UI thread: 2
Number Slow bitmap uploads: 0
Number Slow issue draw commands: 2
Number Frame deadline missed: 2
HISTOGRAM: 5ms=0 6ms=0 7ms=0 8ms=0 9ms=0 10ms=0 11ms=0 12ms=0 13ms=0 14ms=0 15ms=0 16ms=0 17ms=0 18ms=0 19ms=0 20ms=0 21ms=0 22ms=0 23ms=0 24ms=0 25ms=0 26ms=0 27ms=0 28ms=0 29ms=0 30ms=0 31ms=0 32ms=0 34ms=0 36ms=0 38ms=0 40ms=0 42ms=0 44ms=0 46ms=0 48ms=0 53ms=0 57ms=0 61ms=0 65ms=0 69ms=0 73ms=0 77ms=0 81ms=0 85ms=0 89ms=0 93ms=0 97ms=0 101ms=0 105ms=0 109ms=0 113ms=0 117ms=0 121ms=0 125ms=0 129ms=0 133ms=0 150ms=0 200ms=0 250ms=0 300ms=0 350ms=0 400ms=0 450ms=1 500ms=0 550ms=0 600ms=0 650ms=0 700ms=0 750ms=0 800ms=0 850ms=0 900ms=0 950ms=0 1000ms=1 1050ms=0 1100ms=0 1150ms=0 1200ms=0 1250ms=0 1300ms=0 1350ms=0 1400ms=0 1450ms=0 1500ms=0 1550ms=0 1600ms=0 1650ms=0 1700ms=0 1750ms=0 1800ms=0 1850ms=0 1900ms=0 1950ms=0 2000ms=0 2050ms=0 2100ms=0 2150ms=0 2200ms=0 2250ms=0 2300ms=0 2350ms=0 2400ms=0 2450ms=0 2500ms=0 2550ms=0 2600ms=0 2650ms=0 2700ms=0 2750ms=0 2800ms=0 2850ms=0 2900ms=0 2950ms=0 3000ms=0 3050ms=0 3100ms=0 3150ms=0 3200ms=0 3250ms=0 3300ms=0 3350ms=0 3400ms=0 3450ms=0 3500ms=0 3550ms=0 3600ms=0 3650ms=0 3700ms=0 3750ms=0 3800ms=0 3850ms=0 3900ms=0 3950ms=0 4000ms=0 4050ms=0 4100ms=0 4150ms=0 4200ms=0 4250ms=0 4300ms=0 4350ms=0 4400ms=0 4450ms=0 4500ms=0 4550ms=0 4600ms=0 4650ms=0 4700ms=0 4750ms=0 4800ms=0 4850ms=0 4900ms=0 4950ms=0
Font Cache (CPU):
  Size: 4.84 kB 
  Glyph Count: 9 
CPU Caches:
GPU Caches:
  Other:
    Buffer Object: 63.00 KB (2 entries)
  Image:
    Texture: 6.23 KB (1 entry)
  Scratch:
    Buffer Object: 64.00 KB (2 entries)
    RenderTarget: 78.09 KB (7 entries)
    Texture: 1.00 MB (1 entry)
Other Caches:
                         Current / Maximum
  VectorDrawableAtlas    0.00 kB /   0.00 KB (entries = 0)
  Layers Total           0.00 KB (numLayers = 0)
Total GPU memory usage:
  1264959 bytes, 1.21 MB (133.23 KB is purgeable)


Pipeline=Skia (OpenGL)

Layout Cache Info:
  Usage: 3/5000 entries
  Hit ratio: 6/9 (0.666667)
Profile data in ms:

    br.com.gomus.androidapp/br.com.gomus.androidapp.ui.main.MediaPlayerActivity/android.view.ViewRootImpl@a9729ce (visibility=0)
View hierarchy:

  br.com.gomus.androidapp/br.com.gomus.androidapp.ui.main.MediaPlayerActivity/android.view.ViewRootImpl@a9729ce
  40 views, 45,61 kB of display lists


Total ViewRootImpl: 1
Total Views:        40
Total DisplayList:  45,61 kB
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the network section of the **Android Studio Profiler.** The recent network connections took **734 ms**. I do not know if it is good or bad. I was thinking maybe that was the problem. That is the last connection and after that, the app is closed by the device immediately.

[image]

I am waiting your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still waiting for help, and I am still working on this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand this is a restriction by the device because my application does not have a **google play certification**. The only way is rooting the device and let run those apps that does not have that certification too. However rooting this device is also impossible. The device is not root-able. Do not try to pay some services that saying we can root any device. Well they could not had made.

As a result, we left to use that device. This is the end that I have reached.=)